# Different images in containers

Tags: docker

I want to create separated containers with a single service in each (more or less). I am using the [php7-apache](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/0d23b3d08770889c6cb31e8e5374334879103f92/7.0/apache/Dockerfile) image which seems to use a base image of `debian:jessie`, `php7` and `apache`. Since apache and php in this case are pretty intertwined I don't mind using this container.

I want to start adding other services to their own containers (git for example) and was considering using a tiny base image like `busybox` or `alpinebox` for these containers to keep image size down.

That said, I have read that using the same base image as other containers only gives you the 'penalty' of the one time image download of the base OS (debian jessie) which is then cached - while using tiny OSes in other containers will download those OSes on top of the base OS.

What is the best practice in this case? Should I use the same base image (debian jessie) for all the containers in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a base image from scratch. [Create a base image from scratch.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/)

**From docker documentation**

> You can use Docker’s reserved, minimal image, scratch, as a starting point for building containers. Using the scratch “image” signals to the build process that you want the next command in the Dockerfile to be the first filesystem layer in your image.
>
> While scratch appears in Docker’s repository on the hub, you can’t pull it, run it, or tag any image with the name scratch. Instead, you can refer to it in your Dockerfile. For example, to create a minimal container using scratch:
>
> This example creates the hello-world image used in the tutorials. If you want to test it out, you can clone the image repo

Comment: I don't see how this would help in OP's case. He's already using `php7-apache`, creating a new base image does not change the base image of that image, unless he also recreates `php7-apache`. Even if he did, there would be no advantage over simply using `debian:jessie` all the time.